# ggplot2 X variables not in proper order

Tags: r, ggplot2

This code plots the X variable ordered as <8, 10-12, 12-20, 20+ and then 8-10.
Why is "8-10" out of order?  Thank you.

```
tst1 <- data.frame(
len = c(1.00, 1.038219, 1.040130, 1.078980, 1.186618 ),
pm25=c("<8", "8-10","10-12", "12-20","20+"))

plottst1 <- ggplot(tst1, aes(x=factor(pm25), y=len))
plottst1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an ordered `factor`:

```
mylevels <-c("<8", "8-10","10-12", "12-20","20+")
tst1 <- data.frame(
  len = c(1.00, 1.038219, 1.040130, 1.078980, 1.186618 ),
  pm25=factor(mylevels, levels=mylevels, ordered =T))


plottst1 <- ggplot(tst1, aes(x=pm25, y=len))
plottst1
```